# Is using a wire nut and push in connector in the same "bus" okay?

Tags: electrical

I'm adding an outlet to the attic and needed to tap into the existing line circuit.
The wire nut in blue had 5 wires in it and couldn't support a 6th (which probably isn't a great idea anyway). So I split it off into a push in connector. Is this okay? Is the way I did it with a small piece of wire bridging them both perfectly fine or should I get a bigger wire nut?

[image]

Comment: Depends on the nature of the push-in connector.   Where'd you get it?   What is it?  Is it UL listed for the gauge of the wire you used it on???  (12AWG)

Comment: @KyleB Yes it is UL listed for the gauge of wire I am using (12AWG)

Comment: Totally code compliant, then. But stop stripping your wires with a knife. (Half kidding. You don't want to nick the copper when you strip. A real wire stripper costs nearly nothing and does a clean job.)

Comment: In terms of 'does it work' it's fine.  But personally I do not trust any 'stab' type connecter.  They just don't have the positive contact that a screwing-type connector would.  Be that a wire nut or (preferable) a bus bar.  Anyhow -- I'm not a licensed electrician but I'm an electrical engineer -- Not sure the code limits but man, that junction box has alotta branches for just one circuit.  What a rats nest mess.   Not sure I'd go adding yet another load to it.  No way that was done by an actual electrician.  At least not a sober one.

Comment: If that wiring bothers you, you can get [push-in connectors with more holes](https://www.wago.com/gb/installation-terminal-blocks-and-connectors/compact-splicing-connector/p/2273-208).

Comment: @KyleB -- you can tell that was done by a sober individual (and probably a real electrician) because the circuits have actual labels on them. And it's extremely unlikely that it's 'just one circuit' -- note the multiple bundles of neutrals.

Comment: @kyle b that looks like a possible pro job with 1 exception all of the grounds should be common and connected to the box (a code requirement since there are splices)  the plastic clamps look like raco insiders (I haven’t seen these used by non pros)  I would also say there are at least 3 circuits in this box because of the neutral bundles , in whatever case it is industry standard  for this many circuits with a listed type of box,  and I can say this as a licensed sparky. Other than the lack of a common ground to the box it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like lever locks (32a listed) notice the orange handles on the back side,
if you pull those away from the body the wire can be removed.

As far as code it will probably never be challenged but a purest would say both the hot and neutral need to be the same splicing method.  that code segment is in parallel feeds not applicable in this case.

I am not a fan of backstabs. I have seen two many failures on 15 amp circuits.
The lever locks have a better contact area and almost have me changing as I have not had a lever lock failure (I have mostly used them on lighting fixtures), the other thing with a lever lock is each wire is secured and clamped I have not had a wire pull out .

So would this be code compliant? YES
If those are lever locks would I use them as a pro that hates backstabs? Yes
I think lever locks are better for non pros as each wire is individually clamped and I have never seen one assembled incorrectly, where I have seen lots of wire nuts not properly twisted or 1 wire loose (even from pros).